# How to filter a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter with SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, searchview, firebaseui

I have been trying to `Filter` a set of data that is being fetched from Firestore using the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. Below is the `adapter` which implements the scenario:

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class IncidentsRecyclerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Incidents, IncidentsRecyclerAdapter.IncidentsHolder> implements Filterable {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private ObservableSnapshotArray<Incidents> list;
    private ArrayList<Incidents> listFull;

    public IncidentsRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Incidents> options) {
        super(options);
        this.list = options.getSnapshots();
        this.listFull = new ArrayList<>(options.getSnapshots());
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IncidentsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Incidents model) {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(model.getIncident_image_one())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageViewIncident);

        holder.textViewName.setText(model.getUser_name());
        holder.textViewDateTime.setText(model.getIncident_timestamp());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getIncident_location() + "/" + model.getIncident_desc());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public IncidentsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.incident_item,
                parent, false);
        return new IncidentsHolder(v);
    }

    @Override

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return dataFilter;
    }

    private Filter dataFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        // Will be executed in a background thread
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Incidents> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(listFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (Incidents item : listFull) {
                    if(item.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            list.clear();
            list.addAll((Collection<? extends Incidents>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Whenever the search icon is pressed on the toolbar, the RecyclerView vanishes and automatically the Search FIlter does not work.
[image]

I think I have done something wrong while casting `Firestorecycleroptions` to `ArrayList`.

**UPDATE**
As per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search), Firebase does not support full-text search on text-fields. Also, trying for a workaround where I can cast the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` data to primitive `String`, `List`, or `Array` type so that a local search can be implemented. Algolia/ElastiSeacrch might be a burden to handle.
Please, guide if this update was wrong or illogical

Comment: I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444)** might help.

Comment: Is it possible to create a `local copy` of the Firestorerecycleroptions and run a filter on that ?

Comment: i recommend querying the searched data again , it will reduce much complexity and code

Comment: Agree. But this is not even filtering the data and the recycler view is blank when i click on the seach icon

Comment: @AlexMamo: The article and the video was very helpful but can you just tell me what is in the `data` collection that is seen in the video?

Comment: @mustangDC In the data collection is some data that is not related to the article.

Comment: Can you please explain this part.. [link](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreResults/blob/e7ed18a5005b028206984f1fc11b1e5eff233ecd/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/filterfirestoreresults/ProductRepository.java#L26). Because in [Constants.java](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreResults/blob/e7ed18a5005b028206984f1fc11b1e5eff233ecd/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/filterfirestoreresults/Constants.java#L5) it has a reference ti the `data` collection

Comment: @AlexMamo. It would be of much help if you can explain the same

Comment: @mustangDC Oh, you're right. Check [this](https://i.ibb.co/Xz0mRd0/Capture.jpg) out.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Or will it be practical if the `productNames` ArrayList has more than 1000 items............How can we set/search the `productNames` alphabetically? Can you give some idea about how to implement the same?

Comment: @mustangDC You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Please have a look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428805/filter-firestore-data-alphabetically-to-categorise-reduce-document-reads-in-goog)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Firestorerecycleroptions from the constructor and use only your list without call super():

```
public IncidentsRecyclerAdapter(List<Incidents> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.listFull = new ArrayList<>(list);
}
```

Comment: `IncidentsRecyclerAdapter` extends `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` so it is not possible. I asked that it should filter a FirestoreRecycler which is implemented through `FirebaseUI`