# Filter Firestore data alphabetically to categorise/reduce document reads in Google Cloud

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, searchview

Based on the fact that [Cloud Firestore does not support Full-Text Search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) to date, I decided to ask this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351924/how-to-filter-a-firestorerecycleradapter-with-searchview#comment110281711_62351924) some time ago.  Inspired by this [write-up](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) by [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) I was able to simulate a full-text search scenario on Cloud Firestore by implementation the following from the write-up.

**ProductRepository** class's `getProductNameListMutableLiveData()` method fetches all the `productNames` at once

```
class ProductRepository {
    private FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private DocumentReference productSearchRef = rootRef.collection("data").document("productSearch");
    private CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("SearchList");

    MutableLiveData<List<String>> getProductNameListMutableLiveData() {
        MutableLiveData<List<String>> productNameListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        productSearchRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(productNameListTask -> {
            if (productNameListTask.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = productNameListTask.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    List<String> productNameList = (List<String>) document.get("productNames");
                    productNameListMutableLiveData.setValue(productNameList);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Name List Error: ", productNameListTask.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });
        return productNameListMutableLiveData;
    }

    MutableLiveData<String> getProductPriceMutableLiveData(String productName) {
        MutableLiveData<String> productPriceMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        productsRef.whereEqualTo("prodName", productName).get().addOnCompleteListener(productTask -> {
            if (productTask.isSuccessful()) {
                if (productTask.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : productTask.getResult()) {
                        productPriceMutableLiveData.setValue(document.toObject(Product.class).itemLink);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Item Link Error: ", productTask.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });
        return productPriceMutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

Now my question is:

1. How can we improvise/decrease the `READ-COUNT` on the Cloud Firestore by searching by the first alphabet, which may optimize the case over a large dataset.
2. How can we get data orderly from something like this, so that whenever the data is passed on to the following it only reads the requisite first alphabet
   [image]

```
private void getProductNameList() {
        productViewModel.getProductNameListLiveData().observe(this, productNameList -> {
            productNamesAdapter = new ProductNamesAdapter(this, productNameList);
            Log.d("ProductName List---", "getProductNameList: " + productNameList);
            autoComplete.setAdapter(productNamesAdapter);
        });
    }
```

This is the Filter method which allows implementing the Filter/Search logic

```
private Filter productNameFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<String> suggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                suggestionList.addAll(productNameListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (String productName : productNameListFull) {
                    if (productName.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        suggestionList.add(productName);
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = suggestionList;
            results.count = suggestionList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<String> productNameList = (List<String>) results.values;
            if (productNameList != null) {
                clear();
                addAll(productNameList);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return (String) resultValue;
        }
    };
```

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreResults)

Comment: You say *it only gets the productNames based on the first alphabet at least*. Isn't this what you wanted in the first place?

Comment: Yes. `You are correct`. I will edit the question accordingly. But would it be better if we can `filter` the productNames based on the first alphabet something like [this](https://imgur.com/tVJBVHf) as discussed by you?

Comment: Yes, it will, as you'll always know the first letter of the searched product and you'll be able to store more data than 1 MiB that is allowed for a single document.

Comment: Can I implement the [this](https://imgur.com/tVJBVHf) directly with the present code or should I change and pass the first alphabet somehow inside this [method()](https://imgur.com/IoxMC76)?

Comment: I have not tested your code. You might give it a try, or copy and test my repo.

Comment: @AlexMamo The code I have tried is based on your repo only. It would be enormously helpful if you would guide me to search from a scenario like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ESu6.png), where the ArrayList fields are segregated alphabet wise. Currently, the Collection looks like [this](https://imgur.com/undefined)

Comment: The second link doesn't work but the idea is to have each letter from the alphabet separately.

Comment: The second link is [here](https://imgur.com/UyrCKwr). And `YES` the idea is to have at least the first letter from the alphabet so that we can minimize the size of the snapshot

Comment: As I see in your screenshot, you are using an array that contains elements that start with different letters, not arrays for each letter separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229402/discussion-between-mustangdc-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Hello, I see that you continued the discussion in the chat. Were you able to find the answer to your question ?

Comment: no... is there any suggestions you would like to make.. that would be very helpful

Comment: I believe you should try to copy and thest Alex Mamo repo.

Comment: Yes, I have copy-pasted and tried and that is working great, thanks to @AlexMamo, but I was wondering that if we could create [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ESu6.png) a scenario, currently it is like [this](https://imgur.com/UyrCKwr)

Comment: @mustangDC Sure you can, but I cannot see any benefit. I think you should ask a question regarding that scenario.

Comment: Given that Firebase is tightening the read, write, and other constraints, I fear the wrath of it would shower on me someday like [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d)...LOL ;p